# Validate password with Regex

Tags: c#, regex

I need to check if a password has at least:

- One number;
- One lowercase character;
- One uppercase character;
- One special symbol (.,@ etc)

I have the following in C#:

```
@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]"
```

But this is not validating:

```
"Ab!123"
```

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**

I am using this with System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations to validate a model property:

```
  [RegularExpression(@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]"]    
  public String Password { get; set; }
```

Comment: I think you need to escape the "."s

Comment: I updated my question ... In fact I am not escaping as I have @ before the string

Comment: Actually it's even simpler: you don't have a "." in your "special character" group.

Comment: But I have an ! and still does not validate

Comment: https://xkcd.com/936/

Comment: go [here](https://regex101.com/) and try it... it does match (using the "!"). How are you checking that it is valid?

Comment: @Stan: Unfortunately people still don't use such passwords ... :-)

Comment: I am trying the regex using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations on a model to validate a password property.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plain simple: you do not have a quantifier. Use

```
@"^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]+"
```

instead (see the `+` at the end of the expression?) See a working [demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/lJ1vW8/1).
In contrast to the comments, the dot does not need to be escaped in square brackets (`[]`). Additionally, you can still optimize your expression:

```
@"^(?=[^a-z]*[a-z])(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d)(?=.*[$@$!%*?&])[A-Za-z\d$@$!%*?&]+"
```

Comment: @Miguel: Glad to be of any help.